# Are non-video game questions (Board, Card, etc) allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, site-policies

Do we accept questions about non-video games? With the [Board & Card games site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games), I would guess no, but it is not blazingly obvious from the Gaming Stack Exchange site itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This site is for video games only. Video games require the use of some kind of electronic device, such as:

- A computer (including web/Flash games, etc, and PC-based emulators)
- A gaming console (including handheld consoles)
- A cell phone or similar mobile device (including iPad-like devices)

### Where can I ask questions about RPGs or Board/Card games?

- For Board and Card games, there's [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)
- For tabletop RPGs like Dungeons & Dragons, there's [Role-Playing-Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)

### What about video-game renditions of classic board/card games (Go, Poker, Scrabble etc)?

If your question is *not* about the general rules & strategy of the game itself but instead about the functionality of the video game (e.g. questions about [how to take an action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/13913/28182), difficulty levels of [A.I. opponents](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11810/28182), or how to [earn an achievement/trophy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/188269/28182) etc), then you can ask it here.

Answer (score -8):

Personally I think it's a good idea to allow board games, card games etc.

Unfortunately (for me), the proposal was worded clearly with electronic gaming in mind.

Comment: I agree.  We should allow D&D and Magic questions here :D