# Just video games?

Tags: discussion, topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are non-console (Board, Card, etc) game questions allowed on this site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/are-non-console-board-card-etc-game-questions-allowed-on-this-site)

Are other kinds of games besides video games on topic? How about board games, tabletop RPGs, LARPs, miniatures games, war games, sports, dexterity games, schoolyard games (dodgeball), and so on?

Answer (score 2):

I think, while the overlap between video gamers and tabletop gamers is larger than the overlap between table top gamers and *random group x*, it's still not enough to justify their inclusion on this site. People who know the best way to avoid startling the witch probably don't know much about tenth level mages. (I certainly don't, though I wish I did :P. But all my sufficiently lame friends are too busy with WoW :( )