# Are (logic) puzzle games allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This is not obvious from the FAQ. Are (logic) puzzle games on-topic?

Although some logic puzzles are made on paper, most of them are available as computer games (even the ones that are also made on paper).

So, for instance, [Lights Out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/strategy-for-solving-lights-out-puzzle) was on-topic (but some people thought it should have gone to other sites). Although someone can make this puzzle work on paper, usually it's implemented in an electronic device.

But [Sudoku](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16252/sudoku-gaming-theory) was closed as off-topic. And there are tons of implementations of Sudoku on computers and even mobile phones.

So... Are puzzle games on-topic? Or some of them might be on-topic while others are off-topic? If that happens, what would be the criteria for classifying such game as on or off-topic?

---

Related question:

- [Are non-console (Board, Card, etc) game questions allowed on this site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/are-non-console-board-card-etc-game-questions-allowed-on-this-site)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd approach this on a matter of audience.

- If a logic game has mainly a videogame audience, because it's mainly implemented as a videogame -- think Tetris or Lights Out, it's videogamers that probably have played it the most.
- If a logic game can and *is* played on paper however, such as Sudoku, then videogamer expertise isn't really required and I'd ask on Board games.

  However! If your question is about a specific computer implementation/twist of a classic pen and paper game, then yes, your question is welcome here. For example, "how can I generate a jigsaw sudoku with [Solo](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/)?"

Is there *any* game that can't be played through a computer?

Comment: +1 for "Is there any game that can't be played through a computer?"

Comment: This is pretty much what I believe it should be. Like our policy on board-games and such, it should be in the context of a specific video game unless it is traditionally a video game puzzle.

Comment: But... According to the "Board and Card Games" description, the sudoku question would still be off-topic there (as it is neither a board game nor a card game). Where should it belong?

Comment: @denis Maths, then.

Comment: @Denilson Also realize that it's not our purpose to find a place for you to get an answer on any arbitrary topic.  We just determine if it's relevant to gaming, whether there is another StackExchange site that welcomes it or not.